# Import data in excel sheet from memory stream in C#

Tags: c#, memorystream

I had write excel data in memory stream to achieve one of my functionality.Now I want data which is in memory stream to get it import in new excel sheet.Please suggest how can i achieve this .

```
    public static byte[] chunk(byte[] incomingArray)
    {

        int chunkSize = 32768;
        byte[] outboundBuffer = new byte[chunkSize];


        int incomingOffset = 0;

        using (MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (incomingOffset < incomingArray.Length)
            {
                int length =
                   Math.Min(outboundBuffer.Length, incomingArray.Length - incomingOffset);


                Buffer.BlockCopy(incomingArray, incomingOffset,
                                 outboundBuffer, 0,
                                 length);
                ms1.Write(outboundBuffer, 0, length);
               incomingOffset += length;
            }
            return ms1.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am unable to find any excel-related code in your post! what have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @SanchoPanza In my chunk method you can see that i am writing byte array data in memory stream.Now from memory stream , i want this data to get load in new excel sheet.

Comment: using EPPlus, `var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream);`

Comment: to put it more precise: this site is not a code writing service. please do some research on the C#-2-Excel topic yourself and come back when you encounter an actual problem. Also -looking at your history of questions- you may should take a look at the 'Asking' section in the HelpCenter of StackOverflow.